# Using a wildcard in cfqueryparam - Coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Having a bit of trouble inserting a LIKE and using a wildcard within my parameter in my query using coldfusion. Here is what currently works:

```
<cfquery name="sample" datasource="database"><!---Take the query here--->
    SELECT * <!---select all--->
    FROM table <!---from the table "table"
    WHERE 
    <cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(selectList1)#" index="i">
        #ListGetAt(selectList1, i)# = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ListGetAt(selectList2,i)#" /> <!---
                                                    search column name = query parameter

                                                    using the same index in both lists
                                                    (selectList1) (selectList2) --->
    <cfif i neq listLen(selectList1)>AND</cfif> <!---append an "AND" if we are on any but
                                                the very last element of the list (in that
                                                case we don't need an "AND"--->
    </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

---

My goal is to get the code somewhere where I can type in a parameter like so (but it is not working currently - Error reads cannot execute query)

```
<cfquery name="sample" datasource="database"><!---Take the query here--->
    SELECT * <!---select all--->
    FROM table <!---from the table "table"
    WHERE 
    <cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(selectList1)#" index="i">
        #ListGetAt(selectList1, i)# LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#ListGetAt(selectList2,i)#%" /> <!---
                                                    search column name = query parameter

                                                    using the same index in both lists
                                                    (selectList1) (selectList2) --->
    <cfif i neq listLen(selectList1)>AND</cfif> <!---append an "AND" if we are on any but
                                                the very last element of the list (in that
                                                case we don't need an "AND"--->
    </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I suggest turning on debugging, copy the query it generates and then running it in your query analyzer. I usually can find all my mistakes that way.

Comment: That syntax should work. I use the same thing against MS SQL Server. Could one of the list items be empty and that is causing the query to error?

Comment: @Miguel-F No. The query turns up in code section #1 but not in the code section #2

Comment: @JimRilye - Not sure I follow. What do you mean _the query turns up in code section #1_?

Comment: This is odd as it looks fine. Try taking out the cfqueryparam and substituting it with '%' + #ListGetAt(selectList2,i)# + '%'

Comment: @Miguel-F, what I mean to say is it doesn't execute the query with the second code example, an "Error executing query" appears.

Comment: @JimRilye - Wait, you don't want to open up your query to attacks. Keep the `cfqueryparam` tags. It should be working.  Try this, replace your `<cfquery>` tags with `<cfoutput>` tags. Obviously the query will not run but what this does is show you the output of the code within those tags (ie your generated sql code). If you don't spot the error then post the output here and let us take a look.

Comment: @Miguel-F, are you suggesting I query within '<cfoutput>' tags?

Comment: @JimRilye - No. Let me post an answer with my suggestion. These comments are too limited.

Comment: @Miguel-F - It is vulnerable anyway, since you cannot protect column names. ie this part `#ListGetAt(selectList1, i)#`

Comment: I mentioned this simply for a sanity check as the code looks fine and I'm half expecting him to see an error with concatenating the "strings". The cfqueryparam can be excluded if your input is sanitized prior.

Comment: @Leigh I am not worried about vulnerability as it will be distributed to registered people (if its a problem I will worry about it when the code is live to use for clients) - the query is the more pressing matter at hand

Comment: *Re: I will worry about it when the code is live* @JimRilye - I understand you are just trying to fix the syntax error right now, but the time to secure your code is *before* you get hacked, not after the damage is done. "An ounce of prevention ..". In your case it is quite simple. Compare your list of columns against your db metadata ie `information_schema.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks fine. I use the same kind of logic in some of my code running against Microsoft SQL Server.

Try this to debug your code and see the SQL that is being generated.

`<!--- Comment out your query tag to debug <cfquery name="sample" datasource="database"> --->`

```
<cfoutput> <!--- add a cfoutput tag to "see" your generated code --->
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 
<cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(selectList1)#" index="i">
    #ListGetAt(selectList1, i)# LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#ListGetAt(selectList2,i)#%" /> 
    <cfif i neq listLen(selectList1)>AND</cfif> 
</cfloop>
</cfoutput> <!--- add a cfoutput tag to "see" your generated code --->
```

`<!--- Comment out your query tag to debug </cfquery> --->`

This will most likely break the rest of your code that is dependent on the query. I usually just stick a `<cfabort>` tag after the closing `</cfoutput>` tag to stop processing and just show me the SQL.

The purpose of this is to output the generated SQL code to your browser. Look it over and see if you can spot the error. You could also copy and paste the generated SQL into your query tool (query analyzer) and test it that way.